# Chance of an occurrence, once in a 30 year time span?

Tags: probability

I am a little rusty on probability, maybe you all can point me in the right direction.

How would I calculate the following: If there is a chance of 5% inflation in any one year, what are the chance of it not happening over 30 years? Over 40 years?

So in other terms: If there is a chance of an event occurring randomly in any one year, what are the chances of it not happening again over 30 years?

Sorry, I was a little hazy on my original question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A chance of 5% inflation is not the same as a 5% chance of inflation.  The first gives no information to calculate a probability.  For the second, we have a 95% chance of no inflation in a year.  If the probability of having inflation is independent between the years, the chance we don't have any in 30 years is then $0.95^{30}\approx 0.215$

Comment: Thank you for your response: what additional information would be needed to determine a result of my original question?

Thanks